# Trying to make Calculator in android studio, force stopping at calculate button press

Tags: android

recently made a calculator! i made some changes in the code ; i don'nt know why but somehow on pressing the calculate button my application is force stopping. Tried to debug the code using Logger! everything has perfect inputs and the data flow is good enough! its stuck at calculate() button event.

```
package com.daman.calculator;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView display;
    String result,number,operators,calc,number2;
    double rSet1,rSet2;
    boolean a;
   String test;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        display= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        number="";
        number2="";
    }
    public  void onClick(View v){
        Button button= (Button) v;


//        if(display.getText().equals("0")){
//            number+= button.getText().toString().trim();
//            display.setText(number);
//            rSet1= Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(number));
//        }else if (display.getText().equals( number)){
//
//            number+= button.getText().toString().trim();
//            display.setText(number);
//            rSet1= Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(number));
//
//        }
//        else if (a){
//            display.getText().equals( number);
//            number+= button.getText().toString().trim();
//            display.setText(number);
//            rSet2= Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(number));
//        }
         if (a){

            number2+= button.getText().toString().trim();
            display.setText(number2);
             rSet2= Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(number2));

            Log.d("number2 ",number);
        } else{
             number+= button.getText().toString().trim();
             display.setText(number);
             rSet1= Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(number));
         }


        Log.d("number ",number);
        Log.d("number2 ",number2);
        Log.d("rset1 ",Double.toString(rSet1));
        Log.d("rset2 ",Double.toString(rSet2));


    }
    public void operation (View v){
        Button button= (Button) v;
        operators= button.getText().toString();
       display.setText(number+operators+number2);


        test=(String)display.getText();
        number="";
        number2="";
        Log.d("Rest1 in op ",Double.toString(rSet1));
        Log.d("test string in op ",test);
        Log.d("operator ",operators);

        a = true;

    }
    @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
    public void calculate (View v){
        Button button= (Button) v;
       // calc=display.getText().toString();

       // rSet2=Double.parseDouble(number2);
        Log.d(" calc string",calc);
        Log.d(" before condition rset1",Double.toString(rSet1));
        Log.d(" before condition rset2",Double.toString(rSet2));

        if(operators.equals("+")){
        result= String.valueOf(rSet1+rSet2);
            Log.d("Rsult in condition rset1",Double.toString(rSet1));
            Log.d("Rsult in condition rset2",Double.toString(rSet2));
            Log.d("Actual Rsult",result);
        }
        else if (operators.equals("-")){
            result= String.valueOf(rSet1-rSet2);
            Log.d("Rsult in condition rset1",Double.toString(rSet1));
            Log.d("Rsult in condition rset2",Double.toString(rSet2));
            Log.d("Actual Rsult",result);
        }
        else if (operators.equals("*")){
            result= String.valueOf(rSet1*rSet2);
            Log.d("Rsult in condition rset1",Double.toString(rSet1));
            Log.d("Rsult in condition rset2",Double.toString(rSet2));
            Log.d("Actual Rsult",result);
        }
        else if (operators.equals("/")){
            result= String.valueOf(rSet1/rSet2);
            Log.d("Rsult in condition rset1",Double.toString(rSet1));
            Log.d("Rsult in condition rset2",Double.toString(rSet2));
            Log.d("Actual Rsult",result);
        }
        else {
            display.setText("Error");
        }
      display.setText(result);
    }
    public void delete (View v){
        Button button= (Button) v;
        display.setText(null);
        display.setText("0");
        number="";
        result="";
        operators="";

    }
    public void clear(View v){
        Button button= (Button) v;
        if(display.getText().equals("")){
            display.setText("0");
        }
        else{
       String clear= (String) display.getText();
       String altered= String.valueOf(clear.substring(0,clear.length()-1));
            display.setText(altered);
            if(a){

            }else {
                rSet1 = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(altered));
            }

        number="";
            Log.d(" rset1 in clear",Double.toString(rSet1));
            Log.d("rset2 in clear",Double.toString(rSet2));
            Log.d("number in clear ",number);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the calculate function in particular.

```
 public void calculate (View v){
        Button button= (Button) v;
       // calc=display.getText().toString();

       // rSet2=Double.parseDouble(number2);
        Log.d(" calc string",calc);
        Log.d(" before condition rset1",Double.toString(rSet1));
        Log.d(" before condition rset2",Double.toString(rSet2));

        if(operators.equals("+")){
        result= String.valueOf(rSet1+rSet2);
            Log.d("Rsult in condition rset1",Double.toString(rSet1));
            Log.d("Rsult in condition rset2",Double.toString(rSet2));
            Log.d("Actual Rsult",result);
        }
        else if (operators.equals("-")){
            result= String.valueOf(rSet1-rSet2);
            Log.d("Rsult in condition rset1",Double.toString(rSet1));
            Log.d("Rsult in condition rset2",Double.toString(rSet2));
            Log.d("Actual Rsult",result);
        }
        else if (operators.equals("*")){
            result= String.valueOf(rSet1*rSet2);
            Log.d("Rsult in condition rset1",Double.toString(rSet1));
            Log.d("Rsult in condition rset2",Double.toString(rSet2));
            Log.d("Actual Rsult",result);
        }
        else if (operators.equals("/")){
            result= String.valueOf(rSet1/rSet2);
            Log.d("Rsult in condition rset1",Double.toString(rSet1));
            Log.d("Rsult in condition rset2",Double.toString(rSet2));
            Log.d("Actual Rsult",result);
        }
        else {
            display.setText("Error");
        }
      display.setText(result);
    }
```

and here is the Logcat

```
03-23 20:07:40.372 31484-31484/com.daman.calculator D/number: 1
03-23 20:07:40.372 31484-31484/com.daman.calculator D/rset1: 1.0
03-23 20:07:40.372 31484-31484/com.daman.calculator D/rset2: 0.0
03-23 20:07:40.762 31484-31484/com.daman.calculator D/number: 12
03-23 20:07:40.762 31484-31484/com.daman.calculator D/rset1: 12.0
03-23 20:07:40.762 31484-31484/com.daman.calculator D/rset2: 0.0
03-23 20:07:41.692 31484-31484/com.daman.calculator D/Rest1 in op: 12.0
03-23 20:07:41.692 31484-31484/com.daman.calculator D/test string in op: 12+
03-23 20:07:41.692 31484-31484/com.daman.calculator D/operator: +
03-23 20:07:43.862 31484-31484/com.daman.calculator D/number2: 1
03-23 20:07:43.862 31484-31484/com.daman.calculator D/rset1: 12.0
03-23 20:07:43.862 31484-31484/com.daman.calculator D/rset2: 1.0
03-23 20:07:44.612 31484-31484/com.daman.calculator D/number2: 10
03-23 20:07:44.612 31484-31484/com.daman.calculator D/rset1: 12.0
03-23 20:07:44.612 31484-31484/com.daman.calculator D/rset2: 10.0
03-23 20:07:47.292 31484-31484/com.daman.calculator E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: com.daman.calculator, PID: 31484
                                                                      java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5232)
                                                                          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21289)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5885)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5232) 
                                                                          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21289) 
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5885) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687) 
                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
                                                                          at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
                                                                          at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:139)
                                                                          at com.daman.calculator.MainActivity.calculate(MainActivity.java:89)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                                          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5232) 
                                                                          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21289) 
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5885) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
```

Comment: We're going to need to see the stacktrace from when the app crashes

Comment: let me update the post

Answer (score 2):

The error you should be paying attention to is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
  at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
  at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:139)
  at com.daman.calculator.MainActivity.calculate(MainActivity.java:89)
  ...
```

Which is caused by the following line:

```
Log.d(" calc string",calc);
```

You are trying to log `calc`, which happens to be `null`, and this is not allowed, hence the error. You can work around this by doing the following

```
Log.d(" calc string", "" + calc);
```